# How to run Whatsapp without a smartphone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I need to access messages on a specific Whatsapp group but I don't have any smartphone (and don't want to acquire one). I have a "dumbphone" from which I can receive and send SMS and calls but not much more.

I have access to a tablet, running on android, but with no SIM card. When I try to use Whatsapp there it requires me to scan a QR code with my phone (which is not possible).
I also own a computer on which I managed to run the command-line version of Android-x86 in a virtual machine. I have absolutely no clue about how to access Whatsapp from there.

What would be the best way for me to access those messages?

Comment: So you have installed Whatsapp app from PlayStore on your tablet (not web version of Whatsapp)?

Comment: @Robert I don't know, what is the difference?

Comment: The one is installed from PlayStore the other runs in a web browser like Chrome.

Comment: @Robert Then I think I tried to use the web version, will it work easily with the app from the PlayStore?

Comment: The web version is always just an add-on of the app-version and does not work alone. So just install the app and use the cellular number of your phoen for the SMS number.

Comment: Install Whatsapp app from Play Store in your tablet. Register your phone number in Whatsapp running in that tablet. Enter the OTP, that you would receive on your dumb phone, in Whatsapp. That's it. Your Whatsapp would now work on your tablet with no sim card. Same goes for Android emulator from Android Studio (Google).